# iPad 3 - not automatically backing up (iOS7)

Tags: icloud, backup, ios, ipad

I have an iPhone 5 and a iPad 3, both running the latest versions of iOS7.

Both are attached to the same iCloud account, which has just over 3GB free space.

My iPhone is charged every night and backs up to iCloud as it should. The iPad however, is charged maybe once a week but is always connected to WiFi when it is charged. Despite this, I keep getting the message telling me that it hasn't been backed up in two weeks.

Basically, my question is, why would the iPad not back up automatically even though it is set to automatically back up, it's on charge, connected to WiFi and there is plenty of space on my iCloud account?

Comment: What do you see when you hit the back-up button yourself?

Comment: @Robuust If I backup manually, it works fine! It's just the automated part that seems to not work...